# S3 Notifications to SQS: "Unable to validate the following destination configurations"

Tags: php, aws-sdk

I am trying to create S3 bucket notification with SQS.

```
$downArn = $client->getQueueArn($downUrl);

$client->addPermission([
    'QueueUrl' => $downUrl,
    'Label' => 'S3Watcher',
    'AWSAccountIds' => [
        'AWS' => '*' // This will throw error; Setting to plain * does not work too
    ],
    'Actions' => ['*']
]);

$s3->putBucketNotificationConfiguration([
    'Bucket' => 's3-to-sqs-test',
    'QueueConfigurations' => [
        [
            'Id' => 'Files upload watcher',
            'QueueArn' => $downArn,
            'Events' => [
                's3:ObjectCreated:Put',
            ],
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Problem is that without permission I can't create notification, I receive error

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations

When manually going to SQS and adding permission, there I can mark `Everybody (*)` for all users, but I can't make same from PHP side.

**TL;DR** How to add SQS permission for every Principal (AWSAccountIds) using PHP AWS SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's AWS SDK limitation in SDK v2. You can bypass this by setting `Attributes > Policy` as JSON string when creating SQS.

```
$client
    ->createQueue([
        'QueueName' => $name,
        'Attributes' => [
            'Policy' => json_encode([
                'Version' => '2012-10-17',
                'Id' => $id,
                'Statement' => [
                    [
                        'Sid' => 'Sid1',
                        'Effect' => 'Allow',
                        'Principal' => '*',
                        'Action' => 'SQS:*',
                        'Resource' => 'arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*',
                    ]
                ],
            ]),
        ]
    ])
```

`Resource` has format `arn:aws:{service}:{region}:{accountID}:{resourceName}` so I just putted `*` to apply for any region from any account and resource.

`Id` and `Sid` seems to allow any text.

`Version` must be `2012-10-17`